# Looking for a countdown app where I can set value in days

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu

Looking for countdown app where I can set value in days.

There're apps that allow to set hrs:mins:secs, but I want to set in days.

For example, Windows 7 has [this sort of countdown app](http://win7gadgets.com/clock/countdown_gadget.html#.U827WXWSz0o).

Comment: Your best bet would be to check the Software Center. If there is nothing there, I'm sure there is something on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Screenlets:

```
sudo apt-get install screenlets screenlets-pack-all
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Try this[image: A quick google search]

[image: Post with a similar question]

[image: Answer]

If you can't see the picture, the app is called Alarm Clock.I hope this helped your issue, if you need any more help just ask!

Comment: Alarm Clock doesn't work with days.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought it was the only one that did

Comment: I'm sure because I already have it installed.